# Issue getting Laravel up and running

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get a `Laravel` project running on my `localhost`. I've download `composer` and run the following command in my `web directory` of the `localhost`and it creates a `laravel` project for me which I can then navigate through and explore the various files and folders it contains. I can even open up the structure by going to this `URL`:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-test

http://localhost/learning-laravel/ <---- Displays the files in my browser.
```

My problem is that by default should the `public` directory not get opened and the user redirected to the `home` view as this is what it says in the `routes.php` file

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

When I go to this `URL` I get an error `http://localhost/laravel-test/public/`

```
Woops, looks like something went wrong
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

EDIT: set `debug` to `true` in the `app.php` file located in the config folder. Apparently this is my issue:

```
RuntimeException 
OpenSSL extension is required
```

**apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini**

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**php5.5.12\php.ini**

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I am using `WAMP` I've ensured that the following extensions are uncommented in my `php.ini` files.

Comment: So add/enable the openssl extension to your PHP

Comment: I've checked my `php.ini` file and it appears to already be included

Comment: Have you checked the right php.ini file? You probably have different files for CLI and for Webserver

Comment: I don't know if my edit provides any more information, I've edited the `.ini` in the webservers `bin` and also in my `php` folder

Comment: use `php -i | grep ini` (on the CLI) or `phpinfo()` in a php file to find out which *.ini is being loaded

Comment: `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini` - but I've removed the semicolon from this

Comment: I've also read `composer` uses the `php.ini` file located in `php5.5.12` so I've edited that as well and still no joy

Answer (score 0):

have you restarted apache since you updated your php.ini files?

EDIT:

If you haven't, try installing openssl from a binary. I believe the php extension is just an adapter.
https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

Comment: Yes I have, just did it there as well to make sure

Comment: See edit :) I remember having a similar issue when using laravel on windows but I also remember it being really obvious once I fixed it.

Comment: I'll try that now @WillVolin

Comment: run ```php --ini``` in the command line - enable it in the displayed php.ini's (if you haven't already) - other than that, i'm not really sure why its not working...

Comment: Nope unfortunately that did not work either. Many thanks for you help though! I don't know if it changes anything but the first time I created the project and navigated to `/public/` I could see the laravel logo. I then made a change to the `default` route and the problem arose regarding `openSSL` I've since created new projects and still same issue. I don't know what's up. Very annoying

Comment: Can you post the new route you made that causes the error?